# Virtualbox - Set up two linux hosts with static IP with connectivity for ansible

Tags: virtualbox

My goal is to have two linux VMs with VirtualBox on Windows 10. These two VMs should have static IP, able to connect each other(same network), and should have internet connection of host Windows machine to install software packages.

I installed a CentOS VM on a VirtualBox in Windows 10 and able to start it. I want to setup a network with the requirement above and possibly clone the second VM.

Please guide on the setup steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goal is to have two linux VMs with VirtualBox on Windows 10. These
> two VMs should have static IP, able to connect each other(same
> network).

You should use Bridged Network for this so that the VM static IP can be assigned from the network serving the host. Then each machine will be able to see (ping) each other machine.

The NAT engine in the Virtualizing software is DHCP in nature and if you try to set it up as static, it may change when you reset the NAT engine to correct for some issue.

Comment: I have set bridged network from Virtualbox. ifconfig shows enp0s3, lo and virbr0 which one should I set for static IP.

Comment: Probably use enp0s3 as vribr0 is your NAT connection.

Comment: Static ip not taking effect after restart. I still get inet 192.168.1.11  as IP. --- cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=4d868e53-d291-4872-90c8-f013fdf21c3a
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1

Comment: Check the DHCP range of your network.  This is likely your router. Make sure you assign the static IP outside that range. Try assigning your Windows 10 host to a static IP outside the router DHCP range as well.